# Disable/Hide the Filter ability in the Options Dialog in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

Does anybody know how to Disable/Hide the Filter ability in Options Dialog in Netbeans applucation development.

Answer (score 1):

The NetBeans Options Dialog and SPI does not support removing the Quick Search panel (as of version 1.43). I came to this conclusion by reading the source code of the [OptionsPanel](http://hg.netbeans.org/core-main/file/182bf53affe0/options.api/src/org/netbeans/modules/options/OptionsPanel.java). The quick search panel is always added to the dialog.